# Integrate $\int_0^1\frac{\text{sech}^{-1}(x)(1-2x^2)}{1+4x^4}dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I'm having problem to evaluate this integral.

$$\int_0^1\frac{\text{sech}^{-1}(x)(1-2x^2)}{1+4x^4}dx.$$

Where should I start?

I know that $\text{sech}^{-1}(x)=\ln \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right )$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of variables $s = \text{sech}(x)$ makes this into

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{s (\cosh(s)^2 - 2) \sinh(s)}{\cosh(s)^4+4}\; ds $$

Now $\cosh(s) > 1$, and for $c > 1$ we have
$$ \frac{c^2-2}{c^4+4} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\cos(k\pi/2) + \sin(k\pi/2))  2^{k-1}/c^{2k} $$
It seems to me that
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{s \sinh(s)}{\cosh(s)^{2k}}\; ds 
= \frac{2^{1-2k} \pi (2k-2)!}{(k-1)!^2 (2k-1)}$$

so your integral becomes

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\cos(k\pi/2) + \sin(k\pi/2)) \frac{2^{-k}\pi (2k-2)!}{(k-1)!^2(2k-1)} = \frac{\pi}{2} \arcsin \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right) $$

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid, but where did this identity (the summation) come from?

Comment: I used Maple.  But basically it comes from the Maclaurin series for arcsin: $$\arcsin(t) = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( 2\,k \right) !\,{4}^{-k}{t}^{2\,k
+1}}{ \left( k! \right) ^{2} \left( 2\,k+1 \right) }}
$$

Comment: You're talking about the (c²-2)/(c^4+4) series?